# p:selectOneMenu inside selectManyMenu trouble

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an element selectOneMenu inside element selectManyMenu (component names have been changed).

```
    <p:selectManyMenu id="#{id}MyItemsList" converter="#{backend.myItemsConverter}"
                      value="#{backend.selectedItem}"
                      rendered="#{backend ne null}" var="item">
        <f:selectItems value="#{backend.getMyItems()}"
                       var="varItems"
                       itemLabel="#{varItems.name}" itemValue="#{varItems.id}"/>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" title="#{item.title}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{item.subId}" converter="#{backend.subItemsConverter}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{backend.onSubItemClick}"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{backend.subItems}" var="varSubItems"
                               itemLabel="#{varSubItems.name}"
                               itemValue="#{varSubItems.id}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:selectManyMenu>
```

They are displayed normally, but when I change the value of the selectOneMenu in one line, it changes in all. What am I doing wrong?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGpXY.png)

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ You are trying to nest components in a way that was never intended to be a usecase. So it is most likely Just not supported

Comment: Solution for me: use p:dataTable instead of p:selectManyMenu. In this case all works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <p:remoteCommand name="subItemChange" action="#{backend.onSubItemChange}"
                     process="@this"
                     update="@form:ButtonsPanel"/>
    <p:dataTable id="#{id}MyItemsListReadOnly" converter="#{backend.myItemsConverter}"
                 value="#{backend.selectedItem}"
                 rendered="#{backend ne null}" var="item">
        <p:column style="width: 50%">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" title="#{item.title}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width: 50%">
            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{item.subId}" converter="#{backend.subItemsConverter}"
                             onchange="subItemChange();" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{backend.subItems}" var="varSubItems"
                           itemLabel="#{varSubItems.name}"
                           itemValue="#{varSubItems.id}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

dataTable saved my time. In addition, to call onSubItemChange from it, need to use remoteCommand. Hope this helps to somebody.